# Animate navbar on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

When scrolling down the page on a desktop -  The navbar fixes to the top of the page but it doesn't seem to animate. How can i add a animation/transition effect so that it moves naturally when scrolling?

Code Example: http://codepen.io/gza/pen/ygjpBy

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#slide"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more..what kind of transition effect do you want?

Comment: If you scroll down just past the 150px mark on the header nav  (as it fixes to the top) you'll notice it jumps instead of transitioning just. Not sure if an i need some sort of animation or javascript to fix it..